# How do I load a form depending on the input of a textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input

So here's what I have.
There's this dropdown box, with values, lets say A, B, C.

Now, when A is selected, I want to load form A underneath it. Similarly, when B and C are selected, I want to load their respective forms underneath my drop down box?

Is this possible with jQuery, and if so, how would I go about doing it? I don't have much experience with Javascript, but I have learnt a lot (though how much I remember, I'm not sure)

Cheers!

EDIT: Thanks guys! Is there anyway to do it with an input instead of a dropdown box?

Comment: do you load forms from ajax? if so, do you have server-side addresses where each form can be loaded from?

Comment: Is exactly the same with input, but what will happen if user inputs a term for which there isnt a form?

Comment: Hm, fair point, I only want the input because I've got autocomplete working with it (from jQuery UI)

Comment: It can be done with input, but then you must somehow limit what user can enter (i.e. you may want to add autocomplete to input field). My example (jsfiddle) will work the same if you replace select with input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samplecode:

```
$('#youdropdownboxIdGoeshere').change(function() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "yourfile.php?show="+$(this).val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#divForResulthere').html(html);
        }
    }):
});
```

And then you have to make the php-file this points to. In the script, decide what menu to display and echo the whole dynamic dropdown. The content will then be parsed by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .change() event of the dropdown.

For what than happens you basically have two options. Either the Forms are already sent to the user at the beginning, and in your dropdown change event you just use the .show() function to display the chosen form - or you could use a function like .load() or .ajax() to load the form dynamically from the server. First one will be faster on selection but more data will be sent to the user on pageload. I would choose the first one if you have a small number of small forms, and the second if you have either a lot of forms or big ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can place url to form in value of specific dropdown option, and then load it using jquery.load, or $.ajax. If you simply want to load html, jquery load will be enough for you (it is a shortcut for $.ajax get)

Here is sample from which you can start: http://jsfiddle.net/Sskfe/2/